# Complex Manifold: Stokes

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-manifolds

*This is a lemma for: [Helffer-Sjöstrand](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1164208/79762)*

Given the complex plane.

Consider a smooth function:
$$f_E\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^2):\quad\bar{\partial}f_E\restriction_\mathbb{R}=0$$

How to apply Stone's theorem here?
$$\int_{|\Im z|\geq\varepsilon}\frac{\bar{\partial}f_E(z)}{z-\lambda}\mathrm{d}z\wedge\mathrm{d}\bar{z}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{f_E(x-i\varepsilon)}{x-i\varepsilon-\lambda}-\frac{f_E(x+i\varepsilon)}{x+i\varepsilon-\lambda}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
*(I'm not so familiar with complex manifolds yet.)*

Comment: Most of us write $\bar\partial f$ to signify the $(0,1)$-form $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}d\bar z$. I assume you're using it to denote just the derivative. I'm not sure what the relevance of your condition on $\bar\partial f_E$ is; what's more relevant is: Does $f_E$ have compact support? As with most integrals that show up in complex analysis, you want to apply Stokes's Theorem to the complement of a small ball centered at $\lambda$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Oh yes I should have mentioned that; I added it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @TedShifrin: And yes I mean only the conjugate(?) derivative.